# batch script--List of active programs via command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

How to find active programs through windows command line?

By active program, I mean any program that the user is using or just kept minimised. Not all running programs/processes we get when we type "tasklist".

eg: If I close google chrome, It still shows in the tasklist. But They are background processes. I don't want to list that process.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use PowerShell?

If so, you could use the line below to get all the processes that don't have a window title.

It may not catch everything you want though.

```
Get-Process | Where {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ''}
```